# Extracting confusion matrix values in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, array, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I am training a random forest model in Google Earth Engine, and I want to output the confusion matrices so I know which classes are being confused for which.

By default, the confusion matrix is exported into a single cell in [[5, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 5]] format, which is inconvenient for downstream use. I want to use a function to place each value in (ideally) a named column, but I am not sure how to approach this as 1. functions can't be mapped to arrays, 2. arrays can't be placed in dictionaries, and 3. I am not sure if column names can even be created iteratively/from variables.

I know I could array.get() each individual value and place them in a dictionary, but I am hoping for something more generalizable for when I change the number of classes (varies from 4-8). array.get() is also sensitive to Out Of Bounds errors, which may crop up in certain edge cases where not all classes are present in the validation data, and I do not know how to handle this.

[Here is an example script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/42faba770d13da732ef751572a15a4d5) to show the type of data I am currently exporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the array into a list and map over that.

```
var a = ee.Array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

// Get the size and make arrays of row and column indices.
var size = a.length().get([0])
var r = ee.Array(ee.List.sequence(0, size.subtract(1))).repeat(1, size)
var c = r.transpose(0, 1)

// Combine, flatten to list, and map to make [name, value] pairs.
var data = ee.Array.cat([a, r, c], 2).toList().map(function(row) {
  row = ee.List(row)
  return row.map(function(elem) {
    elem = ee.List(elem)
    var name = elem.getNumber(1).format("t%d").cat(elem.getNumber(2).format("%d"))
    return [name, elem.get(0)]
  })
}).flatten()

print(ee.Dictionary(data))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1bb4ded28318a2a910d4635a36e6f626

Comment: It does not like that in Row 12, 'elem' is already defined. Do I need to worry about that anywhere?

Comment: Modified this as such:


`var tLength = a.length().get([0])`  

`var r = ee.Array(ee.List.sequence(0, tLength.subtract(1))).repeat(1, tLength)`  

`var tHeight = a.length().get([1])`  

`var c = ee.Array(ee.List.sequence(0, tHeight.subtract(1))).repeat(1, tHeight).transpose(0, 1)`

This will prevent it from throwing an error in a case where a class is absent from the validation data, but something is mistaken for that class anyway.

Comment: confusionMatrix is *always* square, and always starts at 0.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense thanks. I'm unsure if this follow-up needs to be asked separately. I am trying to export my f-scores this same way. As they are one-dimensional, I removed "var c," changed the "var data" axis to 1, and removed the "var name" .cat() step. The function fails due to float values. I do not understand what the issue is since the floating f-score values are not being called in "var name." How can I fix this?

Comment: Yeah, start a new question with code showing the new issue.